# Solaris 10 LDOM Network Change

Tags: solaris-10, virtual-network

I have inherited a Solaris 10 host. At one time, it had 18 guests/LDOMs, but we're now down to 1, which is still business-critical. The host server has changed data centers and come up with a new IP address, but the guest is still using the old network information and cannot be accessed, except through telnet from the host.

I have run sys-unconfig to change the guest networking information to no avail. If I try DHCP, it cannot find a DHCP server. If I try an assigned static IP, it can't contact the default gateway.

It's my assumption that the host virtual networking/switch has something hard-coded, but I have come to the end of my rope in researching how to find or update this and am having no luck creating/assigning a new virtual switch.

I don't much care if I use DHCP or not; I just need this guest to be able to connect to the network. Thanks in advance.